# delphi xe2 installation issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

i have radstudio 2010 installed on my windows7 64 bit
installed delphi xe2 for testing but cannot compile anything gives me following error
[DCC Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(1): F2048 Bad unit format: 'System.dcu' - Expected version: 23.0, Windows Unicode(x86) Found version: 22.0, Windows Unicode(x86)
I think path or environment vaiables are incorrect
i had xe installed previosly unistalled that after installed xe2

Comment: version 22 is XE. Did you install an XE trial ever?

Comment: Try to uninstall XE2 and then reinstall if you removed XE after the XE2 installation...

Comment: xe i wanted to test xe and xe2 both are trail versions. reinstalling didnt help

Comment: Are you running a command line build or building inside the iDE?

Comment: ok sorry reinstalled again today. everything works fine